# C optimizer eliminating unexpected variable

Tags: c, optimization, volatile

The C compiler seems to be optimizing out a variable that I don't expect. The code in question is below:

```
uint32_t GetSysTick(void);

uint32_t timeout = GetSysTick() + 9000;  //9sec
while(len && (GetSysTick() < timeout))
{
    ... some code that will decrement len
}
```

The compiler will optimize out the "timeout" variable. Typically the while loop will exit once len reaches zero but if the process is taking longer than expected once systick exceeds the timeout then it should also exit, of course none of this happens if timeout is optimized out. I'm sure if I define timeout as volatile that should keep it from being optimized out but technically its not a volatile. What am I missing here?
Should I use volatile on the return value from GetSysTick()? (not sure if that is even legal)

For completeness here is GetSysTick and declaration of systick. Both are in another C file. systick gets incremented every millisecond in an interrupt.

```
static volatile uint32_t systick=0;

uint32_t GetSysTick(void)
{
  return systick;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler, how & where is `GetSysTick` declared? See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Note that busy-waiting is not a good idea. Better use interrupts/semaphores/timers/etc.

Comment: What makes you think the compiler is doing that?  Have you printed timeout within the loop?

Comment: @AlexK.: You have a point. But adding code to print the variable can influence code-generation (Heisenberg-Effect). Better to check the assembly code or use a debugger.

Comment: Make sure len does not decremented below 0 (remember negative numbers can count as true)

Comment: There is nothing that can be optimized from the code presented to make the behavior unexpected. The `GetSysTick` might have some interrupt based implementation with some wrongly optimized stuff. Or your loop contents are buggy (which is the most likely scenario)

Comment: I'm using gcc compiler. I showed the declaration for GetSysTick but it's in one of the include files. len is an unsigned so it will not be negative.

Comment: This information is nearly useless. Show the actual code and *definitions*, not declarations.

Comment: When you say "of course none of this happens if timeout is optimized out", is that an observation or an assumption?  It is conceivable that the optimizer is cleverer than you are, and has found a different way to achieve the same result.

Comment: And by the way, `GetSysTick() + 9000` can overflow easily... And it might be very well the case here.

Comment: Added GetSysTick code to question.

Comment: It is also possible that the optimizer has decided that `GetSysTick()` can never equal or exceed `timeout`, which, if correct, makes it entirely reasonable to optimize out that variable.  Can you be confident that such an assessment would be wrong?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Given the `GetSysTick` code it is unlikely. I bet it is the wraparound.

Comment: @JohnBollinger by observation i've noticed timeout is optimized out I could verify that by keeping len from reaching zero and the process will remain stuck in the loop. I do realize there is a window where timeout will overflow but that would also cause the loop to exit early it should never hang in the loop.

Comment: I think you may want to add volatile to the GetSysTick() funtion... otherwise the compiler will hoist it out of your conditional and store the results of the first call to it.  VAR is always less than VAR + 9000, so it is eliminated.

Comment: @technosaurus `systick` is `volatile` already.

Comment: Show the content of the loop please.

Comment: More than the content of the loop, a [mcve] that demonstrates the loop failing to exit despite `GetSysTick()` returning a sufficiently large value seems to be in order here.

Comment: Another possibility that it is just not counting. Or counting with a frequency different from that you believe it is.

Comment: `but technically its not a volatile` why not? It's being changed in an interrupt which means it can change values between read without your program modifying it and that's exactly what a volatile variable for

Comment: @Eugene Sh. systick may be volatile or not, it doesn't matter when GetSysTick() is not marked as volatile (or possibly inline) It needs to be marked volatile or turned into a function-like macro or the compiler may optimize it to only be called once.

Comment: @technosaurus Making `systick` volatile makes the compiler know that it can be modified by way unknown to the implementation, making the optimization you are talking about illegal. So no, a comforming compiler won't do that.

Comment: I constructed a simple test program that uses a timer to increment `systick` asynchronously, once every millisecond, and I ran the OP's `while` loop with a 5-microsecond `usleep()` within and enough iterations to let the tick timer increment more than 9000 times.  I compiled with GCC 4.4.7 and optimization level -O3, with `GetSysTick()` compiled separately from its caller.  The loop exited before `len` was exhausted, showing that the timeout was honored (regardless of the nature of any optimizations).

Comment: The problem is in the code not shown. Looks like the OP have abandoned their question. VTC.

Comment: Sorry was busy for a while. It seems to me the code in the loop is irrelevant i'm showing all the places were timeout is touched. I did run this same code with timeout being volatile and that works as expected. It just seems to me timeout should not have to be volatile, systick is already volatile shouldn't that be enough? I suspect the compiler i'm using might be the cause.

Comment: @user3757374 You are asking for help from people *you* believe know more than you to help. And these people are saying some information is relevant, while you think it is not. So.. if you think you know better, why are you here?

Answer (score 1):

So after further investigating my compiler I found out that I was not using the latest version. Apparently I was on the gnu arm C compiler version 5.2 once I updated to the latest version 5.4 my timeout variable is not being optimized out. Lesson here, is always check for updates on your tools. Thanks everyone for your input and suggestions. Thanks @JohnBollinger to taking the time to test it with his setup.